# How to increment a second primary key column in a table automatically when a new entry is added for the first primary key column

Tags: sql, sql-server

I am trying to find a way to increment a second primary key column in a table automatically when a new entry is added for the first primary key column. I suppose an example would be best here so here goes.

Suppose I have a table:

```
CREATE TABLE T
(
     SecNum INT NOT NULL,
     EntryID INT NOT NULL,
     Value FLOAT,
) CONSTRAINT [PK_T] PRIMARY KEY CLUSTERED 
(
    [SecNum] ASC,
    [EntryID] ASC
)
```

I would run the following statement:

```
INSERT INTO T (SecNum, Value) VALUES (0, 10)
```

My table should look like:

```
SECNUM | ENTRYID | VALUE
-------------------------
   0         0       10
```

I would run the following statement:

```
INSERT INTO T (SecNum, Value) VALUES (0, 10)
```

My table should look like:

```
SECNUM | ENTRYID | VALUE
-------------------------
   0         0       10
   0         1       10
```

I would run the following statement:

```
INSERT INTO T (SecNum, Value) VALUES (1, 20)
```

My table should look like:

```
SECNUM | ENTRYID | VALUE
-------------------------
   0         0       10
   0         1       10
   1         0       20
```

Comment: Wait - in your 3rd example, did you mean for the last row in your **ENTRYID** column to have a value of **3**?

Comment: Something like this isn't easily done - it's so messy and kludgy that I'd always recommend to just forget about it and use a single `INT IDENTITY` column instead.

Comment: @lkaradashkov - I don't think so, otherwise why would it be a composite key?. Op wants that `ENTRYID` starts all over when a new `SECNUM` is added

Comment: Can you give us the big picture of what you are trying to do here?  There might be a better way to structure your DB.

Comment: @Abe - just keep hitting this problem all the time. Seen ways to do this using Triggers but not pretty. Just wanted to see if someone has a good way to do this... Not really looking for a better way to restructure my database.

Comment: @mark_s - you should put that as an answer... After all, it is an answer.

Comment: why triggers are not a good solution for you?

Comment: @anouar204 - not saying that. Just the ones I saw were a little messy. Would be interested in seeing triggers if that's what you are proposing. Looking for any ideas...

Comment: Just do it in the select using `ROW_NUMBER()` instead of trying to store it in the database.

Comment: @DanAndrews `ROW_NUMBER()` may vary over time if rows are deleted, a value determined at the time of insert will remain fixed. There is also a compound primary key defined which cannot be used with `ROW_NUMBER` therefore foreign keys cannot be used to refer to a `SecNum, EntryID` combination.

Comment: @GarethD agreed, however if the records are identical, does it matter? OP doesn't mention a FK on EntryID.

Comment: There is no mention of a foreign key, but it is worth considering. However it is impossible to refer to a value created on the fly. While I agree with marc_s in that this is a solution best avoided, if another table had to refer to this structure it could not be done with or without foreign keys because `ROW_NUMBER` will change if records are deleted, so the link to the other table becomes broken. If the EntryID is purely for reporting purposes then I agree, `ROW_NUMBER` is the best solution.

Comment: @GarethD, I'm not sure how this field could be used as a FK since it's value is not unique.  For example: Which EntityID 0 are you talking about?  SecNum 0 and value 10 or SecNum 1 and value 20?  If the EntityID is to be distinct then just use an int identity and be done with it.  Q.E.D.

Comment: The combination of SecNum and EntityID would be a [composite primary key](https://www.google.co.uk/search?q=Composite+Primary+Key) which the OP has stated exists (`CONSTRAINT [PK_T] PRIMARY KEY CLUSTERED ([SecNum] ASC,[EntryID] ASC)`) is in the schema definition. Composite primary keys can be referenced by other tables just as single column keys can as demonstrated [here](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!3/c45c3/1)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is possible using an `INSTEAD OF` trigger:

```
CREATE TRIGGER TriggerName
ON T
INSTEAD OF INSERT
AS
    -- THIS TOP BIT IS OPTIONAL, IT WILL ALLOW ENTRY ID TO BE OVERRIDDEN IF 
    -- IT IS SUPPLIED TO THE INSERT AND WILL NOT VIOLATE THE PRIMARY KEY
    IF NOT EXISTS 
        (   SELECT  1
            FROM    T
                    INNER JOIN inserted i
                        ON i.SecNum = T.secNum
                        AND i.EntryID = T.EntryID
            UNION
            SELECT  1
            FROM    inserted
            WHERE   EntryID IS NULL
        )
        BEGIN
            INSERT T (SecNum, EntryID, Value)
            SELECT  SecNum, EntryID, Value
            FROM    inserted
        END
    ELSE
    -- IF OVERRIDE ABILITY IS NOT REQUIRED JUST USE THE BELOW INSERT
        BEGIN
            INSERT T (SecNum, EntryID, Value)
            SELECT  i.SecNum, COALESCE(LastID, 0), i.Value
            FROM    inserted I
                    LEFT JOIN 
                    (   SELECT  SecNum, MAX(T.EntryID) + 1 [LastID]
                        FROM    T
                        GROUP BY SecNum
                    ) T
                        ON T.SecNum = i.SecNum

        END
```

[Example here](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!3/776ca/2)

**HOWEVER** this is not very elegant. It could be worth asking is it really necessary? Could you get away with using a surrogate primary key, and use `ROW_NUMBER()` to create Entry ID's on the fly?

Comment: this looks interesting. I like sqlfiddle.com in your example. Never heard of it before...

Answer (score 1):

Your problem can be solved by using an `instead of insert` trigger

```
 create trigger Trigger1 on T INSTEAD OF INSERT
 as
 begin                                  
       insert into T(SecNum,EntryID,Value)
       select SecNum,
             (select count(*) from T where SecNum = i.SecNum) as EntryID, 
             value 
       from inserted i
 end
```

Answer (score 1):

How about something like this:

```
INSERT INTO T (SecNum, Value, EntryId)
SELECT 0, 10, count(*)
FROM T WHERE SecNum = 0
```

It is not the cleanest solution and will perform pretty poorly too. But it should get the job done.

Comment: This firstly requires application logic to maintain. There would be nothing to stop someone opening SSMS and inserting random values not in keeping with the format. Secondly, it only works if a value already exists in the table for the secnum that is being inserted. If the table is empty no rows would be inserted. [See here](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!3/0829f/1)

Comment: Sorry, I am not sure I understand. If the table is empty, won't it will insert 0, 10, 0?

And I am not sure how this requires application logic? 

    INSERT INTO T (SecNum, Value, EntryId)
    SELECT pk1, val1, count(*)
    FROM T WHERE SecNum = pk1. All the data required to insert a row is right there. There is no external dependency.

Comment: Re: empty table, No because if there are no rows in T, then `SELECT * FROM T` will return no rows, so no rows would be inserted (see my example fiddle). Re: Application logic, this method does not force the database to comply with the logic, it just means this particular statement complies with the logic. If the only way to insert to the table was this method it would work, but what is to stop another developer executing `INSERT T VALUES (100, 100, 100)` even if there are no existing rows for secNum = 100. They have inadvertanly broken the pattern, even though it may not have been intended.

Comment: It is analogous with `FOREIGN KEY` referential integrity. If your application only allowed certain values to be inserted (i.e. checked the relevant primary key exists) you could partially maintain referential integrity without actually creating foreign keys. However it still leaves the column vunerable to rogue inserts that are not subject to the same integrity checks.

Comment: Well, there is no `SELECT * FROM`. It is `SELECT COUNT(*)` which will always return a row. But your second concern is completely valid.

Comment: Yep, you're right. Apologies. I missed a semi-colon from the SQL Fiddle which made it appear as though no rows were inserted.

Answer (score 1):

This is how to do it without storing the value in the table (I'm not sure why you want to store it)

**TABLE**

```
DECLARE @T TABLE
    (
      SecNum INT NOT NULL,
      EntryID INT,
      Value FLOAT
    )
```

**DATA**

```
INSERT  INTO @T
        ( SecNum, Value )
VALUES  ( 0, 10 )
INSERT  INTO @T
        ( SecNum, Value )
VALUES  ( 0, 10 )
INSERT  INTO @T
        ( SecNum, Value )
VALUES  ( 1, 20 )
```

**QUERY**

```
SELECT  SecNum,
        ROW_NUMBER() OVER ( PARTITION BY value ORDER BY Value ) - 1 AS EntryID,
        Value
FROM    @T
```

**RESULT**

```
SecNum  EntryID Value
0          0    10
0          1    10
1          0    20
```

If the EntryID changes with SecNum AND Value use this query:

```
SELECT  SecNum,
        ROW_NUMBER() OVER ( PARTITION BY Value,SecNum ORDER BY Value, SecNum ) - 1 AS EntryID,
        Value
FROM    @t
```

**RESULT 2**

```
SecNum  EntryID Value
0           0   10
0           1   10
1           0   10
1           0   20
```

Comment: Surely your first query should read `ROW_NUMBER() OVER ( PARTITION BY SecNum ORDER BY Value )` not `ROW_NUMBER() OVER ( PARTITION BY value ORDER BY Value )`

Comment: The second query (partition over two columns) makes the most sense... if there is any sense to be had.